# Why does `match?` reduces its matching cases when the desired pattern is stored in a variable?

Tags: elixir

Why does `match?` stops matching when the desired pattern is stored in a variable? i.e.:

```
iex> match?(%{a: 1}, %{a: 1}) # true
iex> match?(%{a: 1}, %{a: 1, b: 2}) # true
iex> pattern = %{a: 1}
iex> match?(^pattern, %{a: 1}) # true
iex> match?(^pattern, %{a: 1, b: 2}) # false, why?
```

Please notice the use of the [pin operator](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#%5E/1) `^` in the first argument of the `match?`.

After further tests I noticed that the [matching operator](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#=/2) `=` behaves the same, like so:

```
iex> ^pattern = %{a: 1}
%{a: 1}
iex> ^pattern = %{a: 1, b: 2}
** (MatchError) no match of right hand side value: %{a: 1, b: 2}
```

EDIT:
After reading the `match?` documentation I could not find information on this behavior, either.

Comment: The pin operator is looking for an exact match. Since it couldn't find an exact match, it failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [Pin operator] accesses an already bound variable in match clauses. Also known as the pin operator.
>   — [`Kernel.SpecialForms.^/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#%5E/1)

That said, `pattern` in your example is not just an argument to the match, it’s *a bound variable, having it’s value*.

Pin operator introduces no magic, it simply passes everything as is to Erlang. And in Erlang:

```erlang
V1 = #{foo => 42},
V2 = #{foo => 42, bar => baz},
V1 = V2.
%%⇒ ** exception error: no match of right hand side
%%       value #{bar => baz,foo => 42}
```

While this behaviour does not seem to be expected/natural/consistent with pattern matching in-place terms, this is how Erlang handles it and there is no room to blame Elixir, that brings no additional preliminary handling.

It could be a good question to Elixir mailing list though; since Elixir, unlike Erlang, has this variable rebounding, it might make another step towards more intuitive handling here.